# Laravel4: file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I have this code:

```
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $destinationPath    = base_path().'public/upload/slider/'; // The destination were you store the image.
        $filename           = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // Original file name that the end user used for it.
        $mime_type          = $file->getMimeType(); // Gets this example image/png
        $extension          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // The original extension that the user used example .jpg or .png.
        $upload_success     = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename); // Now we move the file to its new home.
        // This is were you would store the image path in a table
```

And files name in my upload folder are:
public/upload/slider/folder.gif    public/upload/slider/footer_left_line.jpg  public/upload/slider/phpJtC4Jj
public/upload/slider/folder_o.gif  public/upload/slider/mail.gif              public/upload/slider/post_photo_icon.png
 What do you think about this problem?

Comment: Would you kindly describe the problem in more detail? _(From the outset, it looks like this is simply a post with a possibly unrelated question at the end...)_

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line:

```
$destinationPath    = base_path().'public/upload/slider/';
```

With this:

```
$destinationPath    = 'upload/slider';
```

It'll upload files in your `public/upload/slider` folder. You don't need to use `base_path()` and `public` in your `$destinationPath`.

Comment: You are welcome and you should accept the answer by clicking the arrow bottom of my answer :-)